# How to install a DER binary encoded, GOST R 34.10-2001 root certificate (.crt) on Mac?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, certificate, osx-mavericks, trusted-root-certificates

I would like to install [this certificate](http://uc.nalog.ru/crt/ca_fns_russia.crt) on my Mac running OSX 10.9.1.

I've downloaded it, but when I double click, keychain is opened and that is it.

Can not install it with command line also:

```
user$ sudo certtool i ca_fns_rusia.crt 
Password:
***pemDecode: no terminator found
***ca_fns_russia.crt: Bad PEM formatting. Aborting.
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer in your case appears to be "you can't".

Using OpenSSL, I was able ascertain that your certificate is apparently using the "DER" binary encoding format instead of the more common "PEM" ASCII/Base64 format, which is an easy problem to solve.

But that was the just the initial hurdle. The bigger problem is that it uses a Russian crypto algorithm known as "GOST R 34.10-2001", which may not be widely supported in the west. At least, I can find no mention of it being supported by Mac OS X's built-in security libraries. So there's probably no chance you can import it into the Keychain, and you wouldn't be able to do anything with it even if you could.

You might want to look at which third-party web browsers (or email apps, or whatever you're trying to do) support GOST and support using their own set of certificates instead of fully relying on the OS's Keychain and crypto services.